Karma measure each spec elapsed time
In this case I have an angular app and I noticed that some of the test specs are slower than others. I tried writing simple time reporter:
function SpecTimingReporter(baseReporterDecorator, config, logger) {
  baseReporterDecorator(this);

  const log = logger.create('spec-timing-reporter');
  this.startTime = 0;

  this.onSpecStart = function (spec) {
    this.startTime = Date.now(); // Record the start time when a spec starts
  };

  this.onSpecComplete = function (browser, result) {
    const elapsedTime = Date.now() - this.startTime; // Calculate elapsed time
    log.info(`Spec "${result.description}" took ${elapsedTime} ms to complete.`);
  };
}

but the problem is that onSpecStart is not triggered. I searched for some documention but couldn't find anything helpful. Is there some "start" event for each spec?

Isn't the time already on the result passed to reporters? It's used by the base reporter, for example: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/blob/84f85e7016efc2266fa6b3465f494a3fa151c85c/lib/reporters/base.js#L112 (where you can also see the methods a reporter can have).

@jonrsharpe that could work although I'd like to know how much time each spec took

...that is how much time each spec took.

@jonrsharpe thank for pointing me out. I just realised that I'm blind :D There is indeed result.time which is what I was looking for

Thanks to @jonrsharpe I found my answer.
Regarding my first implementation I only need onSpecComplete hook and then from result object access time property and that's it.
function SpecTimingReporter(baseReporterDecorator, config, logger) {
  baseReporterDecorator(this);

  const log = logger.create('spec-timing-reporter');

  this.onSpecComplete = function (browser, result) {
    log.log(`[${result.time} ms] ${result.fullName}`);
  };
}

